# Powershell ISE saves my last inputs and ignores my new ones (Powershell 1.0)

Tags: powershell

Maybe not everyone understand my problem reading the title but I'll explain:

I am using Powershell ISE to make a script which helps me with sharepoint 2007... This script ***should*** download 5 files from a folder which will never change (like a template folder) and before that a file called **"temporary"** will be created on your harddrive (C:/temporary) where those 5 files are downloaded to.

Then a window opens where you have to make 4 inputs which will be used for renaming the files later. (template name: 999999_uuu_customer_projectname -> after: 123456_BAM_Frank_Windows (this is just an example)). Then the files are uploaded and renamed and that want I want to do with my script but...

This useless Powershell ISE keeps my old settings in mind so if I enter 111111 for the first part and then finish the script and start it again it remembers 111111 or a window doesn't open like everything happens random.

Sorry for this long explanation and I hope you can help me with this script (I'll drop the code here)

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

$credentials =$webclient.Credentials

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName ("System.Windows.Forms") 

$fileurl = "https://workspace.cee.xxxxxx.com/content/00000100/Research/TestOffer/documents/"+$year+"/999999_uuu_customer_projectname/130_Offer_Documents/Review_01/" #xxxxxx stands for a value I am not allowed to display, sorry

  $review_comments_year = "1617" #sepcific for the review_comment_file

  $year = "FY_16-17"  #for the general FY file (only change the numbers!)

  $DropDownArray = @("BAM", "PAS", "AVT", "SRA", "NEC", "ITP", "ELD", "RFT", "SEE")

  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form #init -> initializing window form

    $objForm.Text = "Input Window v0.5" #name -> the name which will be display in the top border of the window

    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,250) #size -> set the size of the window

    $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #location -> where the window will appear on the screen

    $objForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D' #sizing -> fixes the size of the window so you cannot make it bigger

#OKButton -> creates a button with the value 'OK'

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button #initialization -> initializes the button

    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,180) #Location -> where the button is located in the window

    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) #Size -> defines the size of the button

    $OKButton.Text = "OK" #value -> sets the value of the button to 'OK'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) #adding -> adds the button to the window

    $OKButton.Add_Click($OKButton_OnClick) 

    $OKButton_OnClick = {

        if (
            ($ParIDInbox.Text.Length -lt 6) -or
            ($ResearchGroupInbox.Text.Length -lt 3) -or
            ($CustomerInbox.Text.Length -lt 1) -or
            ($ProjectnameInbox.Text.Length -lt 1)
        ) {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please fill out all of the form fields", "ERROR", 
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        }
        else {
            $ParID=$ParIDInbox.Text
            $Research_Groups=$ResearchGroupInbox.Text
            $Customer=$CustomerInbox.Text
            $Projectname=$ProjectnameInbox.Text

            Write-Host -f Yellow "$ParID | $Research_Groups | $Customer | $Projectname"

            $objForm.Dispose()
        }
    }

#CancelButton -> creates a button with the value 'Cancel'

    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button #initialization -> initializes the button

    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,180) #Location -> where the button is located in the window

    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) #Size -> defines the size of the button

    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel" #value -> sets the value of the button to 'Cancel'

    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Dispose(); exit}) #closing -> closes the window after clicked

    $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton) #adding -> adds the button to the window

#ParID_Label -> creates a Label for the 'Par ID' input field

    $ParIDLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $ParIDLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ParIDLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $ParIDLabel.Text = "Par ID (6 numbers!)" #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Par ID (6 numbers)'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ParIDLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#ParID Input Box -> Input box for the Par ID input

    $ParIDInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $ParIDInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,30) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ParIDInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox

    $ParIDInbox.MaxLength = 6 #sets max. length of the input box to 6 

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ParIDInbox) #adding -> adds the input box to the window

#Research Group Label -> creates a Label for the 'Research Group' input field

    $ResearchGroupLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $ResearchGroupLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ResearchGroupLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $ResearchGroupLabel.Text = "Research Group (3 letters!)" #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Research Group (3 letters!)'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ResearchGroupLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#Research Group Input Box -> Input box for the Research Group input

    $ResearchGroupInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox #initialization -> initializes the combobox (dropdown)

    $ResearchGroupInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 70) #Location -> where the dropdown is located in the window

    $ResearchGroupInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,28) #Size -> defines the size of the box

    $ResearchGroupInbox.MaxLength = 3 #sets max. length of the input box to 3 

    ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) { #loop -> put all variables from '$DropDownArray' into '$Item'

        $ResearchGroupInbox.Items.Add($Item) #adder -> add '$Item' to the dropdown

    }

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ResearchGroupInbox) #adding -> add the dropdown to the window

#Customer Label -> creates a Label for the 'Customer' input field

    $CustomerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $CustomerLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,91.5) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $CustomerLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $CustomerLabel.Text = "Customer" #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Customer'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($CustomerLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#Customer Input Box -> Input box for the Customer input   

    $CustomerInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $CustomerInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,110) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $CustomerInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox

    $CustomerInbox.MaxLength = 50 #sets max. length of the input box to 50 

    $objForm.Controls.Add($CustomerInbox) #adding -> adds the input box to the window

#Projectname Label -> creates a Label for the 'Projectname' input field      

    $ProjectnameLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $ProjectnameLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,130) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ProjectnameLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $ProjectnameLabel.Text = "Projectname"  #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Projectname'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ProjectnameLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#Projectname Input Box -> Input box for the Projectname input

    $ProjectnameInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $ProjectnameInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ProjectnameInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox 

    $ProjectnameInbox.MaxLength = 50 #sets max. length of the input box to 50 

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ProjectnameInbox) #adding -> adds the input box to the window 

    $objForm.Topmost = $True #topmost -> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost!) forms!

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

    if($ParID -match "[1-999999]") {  #Numbcheck -> check if ParID is a number
        $temp = 1
    } else {
        $temp = 0
    }

    #directory names ->  will be used for creating the directories below!

    $main_folder = "//workspace.cee.xxxxxx.com@SSL/DavWWWRoot/content/00000100/Research/TestOffer/documents/" + $year + "\" + $ParID + "_" + $Research_Groups + "_" + $Customer + "_" + $Projectname
    # above is the "root" folder for the following 4 directories
    $offer_folder = $main_folder + "\130_Offer_Documents" #Offer Document -> the directory in which review01 can be found

    $delivery_folder = $main_folder + "\140_Deliveries_signedContracts" #signed Contracts -> another folder

    $order_folder = $main_folder + "\150_Orders_Contracts" #Orders Contracts -> another folder

    $review01_folder = $main_folder + "\130_Offer_Documents\review01" #review_01 -> the sub-folder of Offer Document where the document are located

    #local file -> called "temporary" which will be created to down- & upload files (without this one the script won't work!!!)

    mkdir "C:/temporary" #C: -> it will be created on the partition called C:

#online files -> those files are created to have the same structure as in the template directory

    #all 5 folder creations are above
    mkdir $main_folder
    mkdir $offer_folder
    mkdir $delivery_folder
    mkdir $order_folder
    mkdir $review01_folder

    #download location (Ethernet) -> says where the files are downloaded!

    $reviewcomments = $fileurl + "uuu-1617-999999-01_Reviewkommentare.xlsx" #reviewcomments -> where this .xlsx file is located

    $AVB_de = $fileurl + "CT_RDA-REE_AVB_intern_de.pdf" #AVB_de -> where AVB_de file is located

    $AVB_en = $fileurl + "CT_RDA-REE_AVB_intern_en.pdf" #AVB_en -> where AVB_en file is located

    $internal_project = $fileurl + "999999_internal_project_categorization_en.xlsm" #internal project -> where internal_project file is located

    $classification_document = $fileurl + "999999_Klassifizierungsdokument_V1.0.docx" #classification -> where the classification file is located

#where the files (the ones above) should be stored -> in the temporary folder on your local hard drive (do not store it anywhere else!!!)

    $review_download  = "C:/temporary/uuu-1617-999999-01_Reviewkommentare.xlsx"

    $AVB_de_download =  "C:/temporary/CT_RDA-REE_AVB_intern_de.pdf"

    $AVB_en_download = "C:/temporary/CT_RDA-REE_AVB_intern_en.pdf"

    $internal_project_download = "C:/temporary/999999_internal_project_categorization_en.xlsx"

    $classification_download = "C:/temporary/999999_Klassifizierungsdokument_V1.0.docx"

#actual Download -> here the files are downloaded using the webclient

    #format -> $webclient.DownloadFile(webdownload, location on your pc)

    $webclient.DownloadFile($reviewcomments, $review_download)

    $webclient.DownloadFile($AVB_de, $AVB_de_download)

    $webclient.DownloadFile($AVB_en, $AVB_en_download)

    $webclient.DownloadFile($internal_project, $internal_project_download)

    $webclient.DownloadFile($classification_document, $classification_download)

    #webUrl -> the Url the files are copied to (the folder on the sharepoint) and during that they are renamed

    $file = $internal_project_donwload
    $webUrlbasic = "https://workspace.cee.xxxxx.com/content/00000100/Research/TestOffer/documents/" + $year + "/" + $ParID + "_" + $Research_Groups + "_" + $Customer + "_" + $Projectname + "/130_Offer_Documents/review01/"

    $internal_project_Url = $webUrlbasic + $ParID + "_internal_project_categorization_en.xlsm"

    $classification_Url = $webUrlbasic + $ParID + "_Klassifizierungsdokument_V1.0.docx"

    $AVB_de_Url = $webUrlbasic + "CT_RDA-REE_AVB_intern_de.pdf"

    $AVB_en_Url = $webUrlbasic + "CT_RDA-REE_AVB_intern_en.pdf"

    $review_comment_Url = $webUrlbasic + $Research_Groups + "-" + $review_comments_year + "-" + $ParID + "-01_Review kommentare.xlsx"

#actual Upload -> here the files are uploaded using the webclient

    #format -> $webclient.UploadFile(webupload, "PUT" ,location on your pc)

    $webclient.UploadFile($internal_project_Url, "PUT", $internal_project_download)

    $webclient.UploadFile($classification_Url, "PUT", $classification_download)

    $webclient.UploadFile($AVB_de_Url, "PUT", $AVB_de_download)

    $webclient.UploadFile($AVB_en_Url, "PUT", $AVB_en_download)

    $webclient.UploadFile($review_comment_Url, "PUT", $review_download)

    #remove -> removes the "temporary" folder which has been created for this script to work

    Remove-Item "C:/temporary" -Recurse 

#open browser -> opens the sharepoint site where the new files should have been created

    $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application #launch internet explorer

    $IE.navigate2("https://workspace.cee.xxxxxx.com/content/00000100/Research/TestOffer/documents/" + $year + "/" + $ParID + "_" + $Research_Groups + "_" + $Customer + "_" + $Projectname + "/130_Offer_Documents/review01/")
    #get the website url (above)
    $IE.visible=$true #show the site
```

**EDIT:** I am using Powershell 2.0 and upgrading is a bit problematic (because of my company) and sorry for the xxxxxx in the URL Line but I am not allowed to display that...

**HUGE EDIT:** I recognized that the powershell version of my company is 1.0 sooo I think I should upgrade ^^

Comment: btw if anyone doesn't understand anything just ask me I will be here 7 more hours ^^

Comment: Hm, the ui part works fine here. After finishing and restarting the popup appears again and values are not filled. Sounds, like your object are not removed completeley after a run in ise.

Comment: yeah that's my problem and what really makes me angry is that if I copy the code in a new file the code works there and in the old file is the code the same but it doesn't work ._.

Comment: second thing: New-Item : **The network path was not found.

At line:38 char:24
+         $scriptCmd = {& <<<<  $wrappedCmd -Type Directory @PSBoundParameters }
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\workspace.cee...Offer_Documents:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand**

Comment: My assumption is that one of the later links for creating the files is wrong (in the mkdir section)

Comment: Maybe you are just missing access rights to create folders there.

Comment: The funny thing is sometimes it works perfectly and I have the right because I am the admin of this page ^^

Comment: `Powershell ISE keeps my old settings in mind so if I enter 111111 for the first part and then finish the script and start it again it remembers 111111` Maybe you should just nullify your vars like `$var1 = $var2 = $null` at the beginning of the code? `I am using Powershell 2.0 and upgrading is a bit problematic` I suggest you to upgrade to at least 3.0 on your machine and test scripts on v2 machine. It will ease your coding life very much - v3 is a full IDE while v2 is too much truncated. P.S. `$OKButton_OnClick = { ...` - I've seen this code somewhere! :-D

Comment: Swap the order of `$OKButton.Add_Click($OKButton_OnClick)` and `$OKButton_OnClick = { ... }` - you can't assign something that doesn't exist yet

Comment: yeah I did change but I am pressing this button like an idiot and nothing happens like nothing is behind it (and yeah you saw that code :D)

Comment: `powershell version of my company is 1.0` - Windows 7 SP1 goes with 2.0 allready. Dont be confused by folder name where PowerShell is located. I have 5.0 and it still in 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0' folder :D To get the version of PowerShell type `$host` and hit enter in PS console. @Mathias R. Jessen, actually, you can. Try it :-)

Comment: @n01d Oh yes, you most certainly *can* assign nothing, it just won't have any effect ;)

Comment: yeah it works but only sometimes the real spot where it seems to 'get killed' is the upload! It says that the link is totally wrong

Comment: furthermore this 'Onclick_Button' function works I know but at the moment it just does nothing ^^ but I'll try and rewrite the code a bit and try the new version because I think it might be useful to put the upload things into the Onklick Button function to check the inputs and only use valid inputs

Comment: okay I found out something very interesting.... Everything works perfect now except one **THING**. If I open this thing the first time it doesn't work with that 'Onklick Button Function'. I just press the button and nothing happens. When I close it and start it again it works without problems, any suggestions? :DDDDD

Comment: @MisterXCT Looks like @MathiasR.Jessen is right and I should apologize. You really should put `$OKButton_OnClick={...}` before `$OKButton.Add_Click($OKButton_OnClick)`. Mostly I use PrimalForms to build forms for PowerShell and it places all onClick events before setting up form objects.

Comment: Thanks you helped me **more than a lot!** ;D

Comment: Btw my program is working and I am very happy to chill sit back and watch it doing my work which would take normally some minutes!